# jquery hover effects all elements with same class name

Tags: jquery, hover

Hi guys quick question..

Im using jquery hover ive got tiles with the same class name with h2 tags with the title of the element inside.. im trying to use hover to make the h2 tag appear when that individual tile is hover on...but for some reason when i hover on a tile it effects all the h2 tags inside all the other tiles.. i just want it to work when you hover over that indivdual tile and not effect the rest... this is what ive got...

thanks

```
 $(".background_overlay").hover(function() {
    $(".text h2").addClass( "animated fadeInUp" );
}, function() {
   $(".text h2").removeClass( "animated fadeInUp" );
});
```

Comment: please share your html sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method to get elements inside the selected element

```
$(".background_overlay").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".text h2").addClass( "animated fadeInUp" );
}, function() {
    $(this).find(".text h2").removeClass( "animated fadeInUp" );
});
```